How do I fix NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in my application?
I am new to Angular and I need to mark two form fields as touched and invalid by default in one of my components. My ngOnInit() currently looks like this:
ngOnInit() {
  this.serviceData.registrationData.search.forms.markAllAsTouched()
  setTimeout(() =>
    this.serviceData.registrationData.search.forms.controls.id1.setErrors({ invalid: true })
    this.serviceData.registrationData.search.forms.controls.id2.setErrors({ invalid: true })
  })
}

If I only include
this.serviceData.registrationData.search.forms.controls.id1.setErrors({ invalid: true })

inside setTimeout() the program is working as it should. If however, I also include the code line for id2, I get an Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'. and the field is not being marked as invalid. The part of the code from my template which is being referenced in the error message looks like this:
<div class="message-error"
   *ngIf="serviceData.registrationData.search.forms.controls.id2.invalid"
>
   <p>{{'REQUEST.SEARCH.symbolsInId2'}}</p>
</div>

What can I do so that this error is fixed and both of my field are marked as invalid? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Did you check https://angular.dev/errors/NG0100 ?

initialize your form in the right state instead of these timout
